# Node.js Undefined (reading 'value') error

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I work on node.js and EJS.
I got:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')" error.

Here's my code:
[image]
[image: Schema]
[image: error]

I can write `id` log but I can't push to my array field.. some needs help

Comment: Please post your code directly to the question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.course` is undefined, try console.log before pushing. It might help

Comment: LoL thank you sir. But i think it's not efficient, What can I use other than console.log?

Comment: Okay fixed, i write button type = sumbit and then fixed...

Answer (score 0):

It's more efficient to learn how to read eroor's stacktrace to spot place where exception was thrown. Also you can use breakpoints to debug why exception was raised, but console.log is fine too